# chsh and $SHELL reporting different shells

Tags: shell, rhel

I changed my shell to csh (from bash) using `chsh` and now it seems stuck in csh. Specifically, what I have now is

```
% echo $SHELL
/bin/csh
% chsh
changing shell for USER
New shell[/bin/bash]: /bin/bash
Shell not changed.
%
```

I'm very confused as to what could be going on here. I'd like to note that I have restarted my session between switching from csh and bash, and that just running `bash` switches to the bash shell again.

**EDIT:** For some reason, it started miraculously working. Any ideas? as to why that might be

Comment: `chsh` won't magically turn any existing `csh` instances into `bash` (to do that you'd have to type `exec bash` in each of them)

Comment: @thrig As I mentioned in the original post, I restarted the session, so that shouldn't be a problem. Also it fixed itself after the 5th restart (without me typing `exec bash`) so I doubt that's it

Comment: what does "restarting the session" mean, exactly?

Comment: @thrig In my case it means killing the ssh connection and the re-connecting to the server, but in general it could mean closing the terminal and opening it again

Answer (score 1):

The `chsh` command does read the `/etc/password` file for the user entry and use that as the value from which to change the shell. So, `chsh` should have the same value as this command prints:

```
$ awk -F: '/'"$USER"'/ {print $7}' /etc/passwd
/bin/csh
```

Whether the **present** value of `$SHELL` also match such value depends on what value it had when the shell started. Setting a value and calling csh doesn't change it:

```
$ export SHELL=/bin/mysh
$ csh
% echo "$SHELL"
/bin/mysh
```

If SHELL is unset it is also kept as unset in csh:

```
% exit
$ unset SHELL
$ csh
% echo $SHELL
SHELL: Undefined variable.
```

But not is bash:

```
% exit
$ unset SHELL
$ bash
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

So, it may be that the value of SHELL is out of sync with `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: I used the value of SHELL as an illustrative tool, but I could tell that it was using csh rather than bash (specifically because my PS1 looks different in csh than in bash). Also I'd like to point out that the snippet of text from the terminal in my original post is immediately after connecting via SSH (so no other commands have run)